# convert json date to javascript date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting table data from json,Here date is displaying as`1238626800000`.
How can I convertit to normal `date` format like`10-02-2017`
code: https://jsfiddle.net/ncdpw7cf/
Any help?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also include the code in your question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have as the number "1238626800000" is a [UNIX timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (i.e. the number of miliseconds since 1 January 1970).

JavaScript Date object recognizes this, so simply try:

```
new Date(parseInt(leaveList[i].leaveOn))
```

instead of

```
leaveList[i].leaveOn
```

new fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/zLaoc00x/1/

In order to format it so it appears as "12-02-2017", you can use a function:

```
function unix_to_readable(timestamp) {
    var date = new Date(parseInt(timestamp)) ;
    return ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-'
         + ('0' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-'
         + date.getFullYear();
}
```

Second fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/7534hwee/2/

Comment: [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time): _"Unix time (also known as POSIX time or epoch time) is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the **number of seconds** that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, not counting leap seconds."_

Comment: If it is less than `10` means how can I add `0` like `05-02-2017`

Comment: @user7397787 try the 2nd fiddle once again, it should formatting as you want (with leading zeros) - https://jsfiddle.net/7534hwee/2/

Comment: One last doubt I know the meaning of `.slice(2)` but i am unable to understand this `.slice(-2)`.Actually array starts from `0` rite? then what is `.slice(-2)`

Comment: negative value means it starts from the end and moves backwards. there is a good example here of this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice#Using_slice()_with_negative_indexes

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your timestamp string to a JavaScript date object, then use the [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method to create your formatted date like this:

```js
function formatDate(inputStr) {
    var timestamp = parseInt(inputStr, 10);
    var date = new Date(timestamp);
    return date.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
}

console.log(formatDate("1238626800000"));
```

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pahund/tytzuckz/1/

Comment: Here how can I get `return day+'/'+month+'/'+year;` this method

Answer (score 1):

This helps me to convert json data to date format..

```
function formatDate(inputStr) {
  var timestamp = parseInt(inputStr, 10);
  var date = new Date(timestamp);
  var a =date.toISOString().substr(0, 10);

  var datePart = a.match(/\d+/g),
  year = datePart[0].substring(2), 
  month = datePart[1], day = datePart[2];
  return day+'-'+month+'-'+year;

 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tytzuckz/2/