# JSON date to normal JS date

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, date, bar-chart

I have a similar problem as asked by **user7397787** in [convert json date to javascript date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451311/convert-json-date-to-javascript-date-format/44113310?noredirect=1#comment75246026_44113310).

What I have is a JSON string with MySQL table data. One of the data is date. I converted this date to normal date using my own code as shown below:

```
 var comp_date = [];
 for (var i in data) {
   var fields =  data[i].myDate.split('/');
   var mm = fields[0];
   var dd = fields[1];
   var yy = fields[2];
   mm < 10 ? '0' + mm :  mm; 
   dd < 10 ? '0' + dd : dd;
   var formatted_date = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + yy;                
   var dt = new Date(formatted_date);
   comp_date.push(dt);
 }
```

This date is used in a bar graph. Now what happens is that the date along **x-axis** is displayed like this `Sat Sep 09 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Time Zone here)` and on **y-axis** the date is displayed like this `1505900000000, 1505800000000, 1505700000000, 1505600000000`. I want date on both side in `mm-dd-yyyy` format.

I tried to convert date with the method explained by **sammysaglam** in [convert json date to javascript date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451311/convert-json-date-to-javascript-date-format/44113310?noredirect=1#comment75246026_44113310) like this:

```
var date =  unix_to_readable( data[i].myDate);
```

But then I got all dates returned with the same value, which is `01-01-1970`.

Anyone knows what's happening or what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisForrence you are right it works that way too. I'm a new be so I dont have much experience in js coding. Thanks for pointing that out. Updated my knowledge.

Comment: what graph library are you using and what type is it expecting? Does it want a formatted string or will it take a javascript Date object and format on its own? You are saying that in the same json object you return two different dates and one set (x axis) display correctly and one set (y axis) does not?

Comment: i'm using chart.js following this example https://www.dyclassroom.com/chartjs/chartjs-how-to-draw-bar-graph-using-data-from-mysql-table-and-php

Comment: The JSON data format doesn't have a Date type. What do you actually have? Provide a [mcve]. Include some sample input in it. Tell us what the expected output is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took one of the numbers you said you were having trouble with `1505900000000`. This code snippet shows how to get it into a readable string (by way of a date object) in javascript. If you run the snippet an alert will show you the date string you are looking for.

```js
var dateNumberString = '1505900000000'; // This is what you get from JSON
var dateNumber = parseInt(dateNumberString); // make it a number
var date = new Date(dateNumber);// javascript will convert to date object for you
var dateString = date.toString(); // make it a string
alert(dateString);
```

Then to format the date the way you want it:

```js
var dateObj = new Date();
var formattedString = getFormattedDate(dateObj);
alert(formattedString);

// This function takes a javscript date object
function getFormattedDate(date) {
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // javascript month is zero based 
  month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;
  var day = date.getDate().toString();
  day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;
  return month + '-' + day + '-' + year;
}
```